# Using pngcrush with git export filter

Tags: image, git, optimization, png

I’d like to optimize png files when I export them (using git archive) from the repository, using a smudge filter. However, if I understand it correctly, these filters work only via STDIN and STDOUT, while pngcrush needs a “real” file.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use temporary files. eg:

```
IN=$(mktemp)
OUT=$(mktemp)

# save stdin to temp file
cat > "$IN"

# Crush the image and ignore regular output.
# Die if pngcrush fails.
pngcrush "$IN" "$OUT" > /dev/null || exit $?

# write temp file to stdout
cat "$OUT"

# clean up
rm "$IN" "$OUT" &
```

Comment: It works. You just have to remember to redirect all the uneeded output from pngcrush to /dev/null; otherwise it will be added to output.png

Comment: Should probably check for pngcrush error codes. You could redirect stderr to /dev/null too, but you'll never notice if something goes wrong.

Comment: Good points about stdout and error codes (and thanks for adding the stdout redirection, @pydave). I added error code checking (another option would be to use `set -e`) as well as better temp file handling (now uses `mktemp` and deletes temp files when done).

Comment: BTW, the backgrounding `rm` is a little trick to keep you from waiting for the rm to finish. They'll be in a temp dir (probably `/tmp`) anyway, so deleting them isn't critical, and ext3fs^H^H^H^H^H^H certain file systems can be really slow about deleting files.